# Facebook login using php SDK doesn't work with my site's own session and cookie settings

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

So I am trying to integrate logging in via `facebook` in my website. Because people who do not wish to use `facebook` can use our website's logging in system, we have create a way to set cookies and sessions. There i want to create `cookies` and `session` variables for `facebook` users as well. 
 However, I get this error :

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/88/10590088/html/Test4/index.php:9) in /home/content/88/10590088/html/Test4/login.php on line 144

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/88/10590088/html/Test4/index.php:9) in /home/content/88/10590088/html/Test4/login.php on line 145
```

and line 145 and line 144 are the last 2 lines below:

```
// CREATE THEIR SESSIONS AND COOKIES
$_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
$_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
setcookie("id", $db_id, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
setcookie("user", $db_username, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
```

Comment: try to put ob_start() at the start of your php file

Comment: Do you have more blank spaces or comments in your file

Comment: ob_start() gave same error. What do mean by more blank spaces and comments. Of course there are...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that cookies and sessions are set by sending headers back to the browser.
You can find a great explanation about why this happens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/2369344).

You cannot modify the headers when there already sent, probably you have some HTML code or blank spaces between line 9 and line 144, try to remove them if there are any or try to move line 144-145.

Otherwise try using methods like [`ob_flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php).(Place it just before line 144)

Comment: Thank you but, I deleted the spacing I had and still the same error occurs. Also, the `ob_flush()` did not work. Just in case you did not realise, the line 9 is in another file called index.php and line 144-145 is from another file login.php. The line 9 in index.php `<?php include('header.php'); ?>`